# Json output string into an array or list

Tags: json, list, dictionary

Hi i am trying to set json output to an array or list, but receiving an error
"cannot convert from system.collections.generic.list to String[]"

**String received in paramValue-**

```
{"0":["1234","2222","4321","211000","90024","12","2121","322223","2332","3232"],"1":["0856","6040222","175002","23572","","","","","",""]}

List<string> strlist;
strlist = new List<string>();

var jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(paramValue);

foreach (var item in jr)
{
   //Need some thing like this  
  // strList.Add(item)
}
```

In order to take "item" values in the List, I also tried `item.Value.CopyTo(strlist);` but got the error  "cannot convert from system.collections.generic.list to String[]".

Actually i need the "item" values to be stored in  List, so that i can pass into another functions.

Thanks

Comment: Where you are getting an error? seems ok to me

Comment: `Cannot convert from system.collections.generic.list to String[]` => this indicates you're trying to assign `List<string>` into `string[]`. Use `ToArray()` for that purpose.

Comment: which line you are getting an error? the current code have no errors

Comment: In order to take "item" values in the List<string>, I tried item.Value.CopyTo(strlist); i got the error  "cannot convert from system.collections.generic.list to String[]". Actually i need the "item" values to be stored in  List<string>, so that i can pass into another function

Comment: edit your question and post fullcode

Comment: `CopyTo()`'s first argument expects an array which has same type as `Value` property of dictionary, but you're passing a list on it. You need to create a string array and use `ToList()` afterward, however I need to see your current non-working code in question body first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over the `dictionary` you have the `List<string>` in the value, so you can not add that value array using `add` to the `List<string> strlist;` `add` expect it to be a single value not multiple, as you want to add multiple values you can use  [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2).

like this

```
foreach (var item in jr)
{
     //Need some thing like this  
     strlist.AddRange(item.Value);
}
```

if you want to use short-one then use

```
strlist.AddRange(jr.SelectMany(a => a.Value));
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, can you please let me know, to use AddRange using Key value.